# what will export { foo as bar } affect when importing module

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am confused about this snippet [here](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html).

```
//------ underscore.js ------
export default function (obj) {
    ...
};
export function each(obj, iterator, context) {
    ...
}
export { each as forEach };

//------ main.js ------
import _, { each } from 'underscore';
...
```

The `export { each as forEach }` part confused me.
When I import this function, should I use
`import { each } from 'underscore'` or  `import { forEach } from 'underscore'`?

When I use the function in main.js , what will be the difference between `export { each }` and `export { eash as forEach }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `export { each as forEach }` part confused me.

It means "export the value of the local variable `each` under the name `forEach`".

> When I import this function, should I use `import { each } from 'underscore'` or `import { forEach } from 'underscore'`?

```
import { forEach } from 'underscore'
```

because that's what the module exports.

> When I use the function in main.js , what will be the difference between `export { each }` and `export { eash as forEach }` ?

`export {each}` exports the value under the name `each`. For the other see my first answer.

There wouldn't be any difference *using* the function except that you'd use a different name.

---

FWIW, the same thing can be done on the import side:

```
import { forEach as foo} from 'underscore'
```

Now you can refer to that function as `foo` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: Thank you. Felix. So according to the snippet I quoted in my question, main.js is importing the first two exports, right?

Comment: `import _, { each } from 'underscore';` imports the default export of the module and the export named `each`. But since there is no export `each`, that won't work.